# Elasticsearch : Marvel and Sense Plugin Installation does not work

Tags: kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I have tried the online and offline instructions for installing marvel and sense, but nothing works. I have ES 2.2.1 and Kibana 4.4.2

I tried

`plugin install marvel-agent`

but i get

```
Installing marvel-agent...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/marvel-agent/2.2.0/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

same error for

```
bin/plugin install license

bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

so then i tried downloading the files and follow instructions on

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html#offline-installation

i tried

`plugin install file:///C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip`

but i get

```
-> Installing from file:/C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip...
Trying file:/C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip ...
Downloading ..DONE
Verifying file:/C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
```

same for

`plugin install file:///C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/license-2.2.0.zip`

and finally for

`kibana plugin --install marvel --url file:///C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-2.2.0.tar.gz`

i get

```
Installing marvel
Attempting to transfer from file:///C:/Users/xyz/ElasticSearch/zips/marvel-2.2.0.tar.gz
Error: ENOTFOUND
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified."
```

Please point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: if you still have question let me know

Answer (score 1):

For me, the last installation instruction required a different format for the url.
file://c:/Temp/ElasticSearch/marvel-2.2.1.tar.gz.  Basically, remove one of the forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

download the Sense tar file from the following link: https://download.elasticsearch.org/elastic/sense/sense-latest.tar.gz

open cmd form kibana\bin location 
then you can install Sense using the following command:

```
kibana plugin -i sense -u file:PATH_TO_SENSE_TAR_FILE
```